# Create user specific information from external files to generate report

Tags: cross-reference

User can generate a report, "user_overview.txt", to output the following information:

- The total number of users registered with task_manager.py. (I completed)
- The total number of tasks that have been generated and
  tracked using the task_manager.py. (I completed)
- For each user also describe:
- **The total number of tasks assigned to that user.**

I am able struggling with the question in bold: how to read the external file and sort the information into user specific information. Or in this case, the total number of tasks assigned to any specific user.

Example of the file user.txt is as follows (username, password):

flower, power

manager, manag3r

The file task.txt is as follows:

manager, marathon, 42km run, 2023-Mar-03, 2023-01-03, no

flower, garden renovation, plant grass and trees, 2023-Mar-03, 2023-04-10, no

I decided to create a list of users and then cross reference that with the lines in the task file, "task.txt". I am thinking a for loop (user list) within a for loop (lines in the task file). However, the problem is using this list to then count the number of occurrences/task for each user. Any ideas??

```
#this part creates the user list
user_list=[]
    user_dict={}
    user_task=0
    with open("user.txt", "r+") as user_file:
        for line in user_file.readlines():
           line= line.strip().replace(",","").split(" ")
           user_list.append(line[0])
        print(user_list)
    
    #This part is meant to count the occurances, but not counting as I wish
    with open("task.txt", "r", encoding= "utf-8-sig") as task_list:
        task_list= task_list.readlines()
        for lines in task_list:
            for x in user_list:
                if x in user_dict:
                    user_dict[x]+=1
                else:
                    user_dict.update({x:0})
        print(user_dict)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Thank you, I have made the changes to my question. Any ideas on the for loop counting??